# Variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

PHP: what is the difference between 
      $varName = "$var \n"; 
from that with a period: 
      $varName. = "$var \n"?
quite confusing.

Comment: I'm so glad nobody answered a simple RTFM :)

Answer (score 9):

The . operator in PHP means concatenation.

You can use operators with the assignment operator (=) to accomplish both affects.

So these are the same:

```
$varname .= "stuff";
$varname = $varname . "stuff";
```

Which basically means, the original value plus the new value.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that the same syntax applies to every mathematical operators such as + - / * %.

eg :

```
$i = 1;
$i += 1;
echo $i; // outputs 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for attributing a value
`.=` is for concatenating

```
$var = "a";
$var = "b"; // $var will be "b";

$var = "a";
$var .= "b"; // $var will be "ab";
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is just to append to the existing string. ie:

```
$str = "i went to";
$str .= "the park";
//$str will be "i went to the park"
```

Comment: Actually, $str will be "i went tothe park". You missed a space in there :-)

Answer (score 0):

in this instance, they both achieve the same effect.
however, `$varName = "$var \n"` initialises `$varName` to `"$var \n"`
whereas, `$varName. = "$var \n"` initialises `$varname` to `''` (empty) and appends `"$var \n"` to the end